# r packages for fused lasso with ordinal response variable?

Tags: r, ordinal, lasso-regression

Could anyone suggest any extant `r` packages that implement fused lasso with ordered logit models?

I've checked `r` packages including `glmnet`, `genlasso`, `penalizedLDA` and `orderedLasso` but none of them includes both fused penalty and generalized linear models...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

huh, turns out the most credible package there is appears to be `longfused`.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`flam: Fits Piecewise Constant Models with Data-Adaptive Knots`

Implements the fused lasso additive model as proposed in Petersen, A., Witten, D., and Simon, N. (2015). Fused Lasso Additive Model. Petersen A, Witten D, and N Simon (2015) Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics 25(4): 1005-1025

```
install.packages("flam")
```

Also there is this shinny app to play around.
https://ajpete.shinyapps.io/FLAM/

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt answer! I'm probably missing something big time here but would you mind elaborating a bit how to apply this fused Generalized Additive Model (piecewise constants) to fused lasso with ordered logit models?

Comment: Perhaps you could start a new thread as it seems like your starting a new conversation now. I would also suggest posting sample code and a specific problem your working on as it best helps the community provide examples.

Comment: ah excuse me if it was confusing but I was asking the same question... I thought the flam package is for a specific functional form of GAM, not necessarily GLM, which is what I was looking for. Did I miss anything?